# How to disable Forced Enrollment on a Chromebook

Tags: laptop, chromebook

Does anyone know any other way to disable forced enterprise enrollment on a acer c720(School gave to us)?
I've tried doing:

- esc+refresh+power and then getting into dev mode but it says disabled
- tried using chrome recovery tool on USB
- after, I tried to unscrew bottom and take out the battery for a while and making sure power is out and then booting. dev mode still disabled
- Then I took out the SSD and tried to wipe it by putting it on my computer. Still no luck.

I searched and all i see is taking out battery to kill the power but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Does anyone know any other way to disable forced enterprise enrollment?

Does the school still own the device? If yes, then you shouldn't be trying to [deprovision the device](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3523633).

If you now own it, you may have to ask the school IT department to [deprovision the device](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3523633) for you.

In any case, here are the instructions:

> **Force wiped devices to re-enroll**
>
> By default, wiped or recovered Chrome devices are forced to re-enroll into your domain after they've been wiped. This ensures that those devices remain managed, and that policies you set are enforced on the device.
>
> **How it works**
>
> When the Forced Re-Enrollment device policy in your Admin console is turned on and you wipe or recover a device, the enrollment screen is the first thing a user sees when they restart the device. This means that the user has to re-enroll the device into your domain before they can use it. If they don't re-enroll the device, they can't sign in to it, browse in guest mode or see the consumer sign-in screen.
>
> Important: If a device is no longer going to be managed by your domain, [deprovision the device](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3523633). This removes all device policies, so the device won't be forced to re-enroll after it's wiped. You might want to do this if you're returning a device, submitting it for repair or selling it.
>
> **Turn Forced Re-Enrollment on or off**
>
> 1. Sign in to the Google Admin console.
> 2. Click Device management.
> 3. On the left, click Chrome management.
> 4. Click Device settings.
> 5. Select the organization where you want forced re-enrollment to apply.
>
>    Note: By default, an organization inherits the settings of its parent
>      in the organizational tree. However, you can override the inherited
>      setting by explicitly changing the setting for the child organization
>      unit. The new setting applies to devices in that organization unit,
>      and any children of that organization unit.
> 6. Configure the Forced Re-enrollment setting:
>
>    - To turn it on, select Force device to re-enroll into this domain after wiping.
>    - To turn it off, select Device is not forced to re-enroll after wiping.
> 7. At the bottom, click Save. Settings typically take effect within minutes, but it might take up to an hour to propagate through your
>      organization.
>
> Note:
>
> - The policy works only on devices that were enrolled while on Chrome version 35 and later.
> - You can turn on this policy for your entire domain, or by organization unit to include only devices in specific
>     sub-organizations. If you don't want this policy to be applied to
>     specific devices, move those devices into a sub-organization that has
>     the policy disabled.
> - To allow the user enter into developer mode on the Chrome device, turn off forced re-enrollment for their device's organization unit.

Source [Deprovisioning and wiping devices](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6352858)

Comment: Dang. Too bad the school still owns. No luck then. But my friend was able to  run crosh which is blocked. He told me he used a knife to change the serial number and get into dev mode. Is this a possible way? Also i was wondering why wiping the chromebook won't wipe re-enrollment. Where is the forced enrollment "located" or downloaded on the chromebook if its not on the SSD?

Comment: I've no idea. Even if I did I can't tell you as such a question is off-topic,  because it (hacking) is against the [SE] [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal).

Comment: “He told me he used a knife to change the serial number and get into dev mode.” Sounds like a big old lie to me. Nothing worse than “1337” hackers bragging and spreading nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still having the issue you will need to work with the admin for the Google Enterprise account to correct it.

You may have to log the device into an account for the Enterprise administrator to get it to grab the updated/un-enrolled status if the device was offline when it was deprovisioned. In some cases I have seen the OU force enrollment lock the device despite being deprovisioned or retied. In those cases I created an OU for the retired devices with all settings allowed.

The Enrollment Settings and config are stored in the bios. 
Swapping memory, erasing, and factory reset will not override it.
AFAIK there is not a way to overwrite the bios without first enabling Dev Mode.
It will just overwrite it with the default bios due to the security measures in place.

This doesn't seem to apply to your situation; are you seeing Enrollment for 'Chrome for meetings' or 'Google Hangout'? If so you will need to swap it to ChromeOS by pressing Ctrl+Alt+H and then selecting NO. It will then reboot into ChromeOS allowing you to login to an account or enable Dev Mode assuming it is properly deprovisioned by the admin.

I am in the process of retiring about 20 devices from my company; ChromeBox/ChromeBook/ChromeBase and Chrome for Meetings(ChromeBox).

Edit: 
Official Response from Google Support on the OU thing.
"For developer mode, make sure that the Forced Re-enrollment policy is set to Disable on the Organizational Unit where the affected Chromebox is located. Then proceed with developer mode."