# Firmware ChromeOS HP x360 write protection

Tags: chromebook, hp

I have an HP x360 2022 Chromebook.  Where is the write protection screw placed on the motherboard in this model?  I'd like to install Windows 10 with MrChromebox.

Comment: They gave up with that screw years ago, there's no way to bypass them at all now - https://superuser.com/questions/1191482/how-to-disable-forced-enrollment-on-chromebook-acer-c720

Comment: @Tetsujin IIRC it's a separate thing. If it's not enterprise-enrolled some models can be flashed with Coreboot and turn the Chromebook/Chromebox into an ordinary PC.

Comment: @gronostaj pls tell me what are the steps to get in to bios

Comment: You need to go into details on what you have tried or this question is going to keep getting closed.

Answer (score 4):

First things first:

**Installing alternative firmware on Chromebooks is risky and can turn your device into an expensive paperweight if done incorrectly.** You're asking very basic questions. If you can't google this stuff yourself, then you probably don't understand all the implications. Stay away from it for now and keep reading on the topic.

According to the [MrChromebox Wiki](https://mrchromebox.tech/#devices) this model uses the [CR50 protection](https://wiki.mrchromebox.tech/Firmware_Write_Protect#Disabling_WP_on_CR50_Devices_via_CCD). The screw was only present in older models.

This won't work if the Chromebook is enterprise-enrolled.

The full guide is provided at the link above. As an exception to the rules of Super User I won't include them here for reasons:

- It's a relatively high-risk operation and slightly higher barrier of entry may prevent a couple Chromebooks from getting bricked
- With such risky operation I'd rather not risk putting another copy of the instructions here that may eventually become outdated or even dangerous