# Unable to unlock hardware protection on ASUS C204MA-BU0448 Chromebook - seeking advice

Tags: chromebook, asus, bypass, jailbreak

We are currently facing an issue with an ASUS C204MA-BU0448 Chromebook, and we would greatly appreciate any assistance or advice you can provide.

We have been trying to unlock the hardware protection on this Chromebook to explore alternative operating systems and settings. However, despite having an experienced IT team member working on the task, we have not been able to remove the hardware lock. We have tried various methods, but we are still facing the same problem.

We wanted to reach out to the community to see if anyone else has encountered a similar situation with this specific Chromebook model or any other Chromebook. If so, could you please share your experiences and any potential solutions you might have found? Are we missing a crucial step in the process, or is there a known issue with this model that makes it particularly difficult to unlock?

We understand the importance of respecting security measures and manufacturer restrictions, so we are interested in legitimate and authorized methods for exploring alternative operating systems on this device.

Images with more info:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Is this a provisioned device? See https://superuser.com/questions/1191482/how-to-disable-forced-enrollment-on-a-chromebook

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're discussing here the subject of
[Chromium OS Docs - Hardware Write protect](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/write_protection.md#Hardware-Write-protect).

According to the docs :

> In newer devices, we've moved away from the WP signal being controlled by a physical screw and to a separate chip controlling the WP signal.
> ...
> That separate chip is often referred to as a secure element (SE), the firmware controlling the SE is called Cr50. This secure element firmware is fully authored and controlled by Google.

The only way the docs mention for disabling this chip is :

> Note that even in case of the devices protected by the SE, opening up the device and disconnecting the battery would still disable write protection.

If the device can function with the battery disconnected, this should be
the solution. However, if not, then the project is hopeless.